# What programs have trouble with case-sensitive (HFSX) filesystems, and how to fix them?

Tags: hfs, filesystem

There are some programs that require a case-sensitive filesystem, and others that require case-insensitive. Even though [Apple warns against using case sensitive file systems](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH8289), in some situations it is useful.

**What programs have trouble with Case Sensitive (HFSX) systems?**

**What are the work-arounds?**

In general, the problem is that the developers have a file in their app called `FOO`, but try to access the file by the name `foo`. In an HFS+ system that is case preserving but case insensitive, searching for `foo` will find `FOO`. That is not the case in HFSX. The general solution is therefore to

1. Find the misnamed file or folder
2. Make a copy, a link, or rename so the expected name is found

Comment: No ability to add answers, but this site lists some software *and* provides explanations how to debug and get them working again: http://www.jms1.net/osx-case-sensitive-fs.shtml

Comment: **MODERATORS**: This question has been closed and voted to re-open already: http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/requesting-re-open-votes-for-a-question 
Please read that and consider before voting to close.

Comment: The meta discussion has no objections lodged to re-opening this, so I'm going to over-rule the closure and ask that people join us on meta if I missed an opinion / reason to close it. Discussion is [here](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/requesting-re-open-votes-for-a-question) and [here](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/requesting-re-open-votes-for-a-question)

Answer (score 5):

According to this question, Photoshop CS5 won't work on HFSX.

[Convert a partition from case-sensitive to case-insensitive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15080/convert-a-partition-from-case-sensitive-to-case-insensitive)

Comment: Apparently, CS6 doesn't work, either. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61665/i-want-to-install-adobe-cs6-on-external-hard-drive-but-cant-select-the-install

Comment: I thought that Adobe Reader had the same issue, but it seems to work on my iMac. Adobe Acrobat Reader DC `2019.021.20058`.

Answer (score 3):

[MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net) version 1.3.2 does not work on HSFX systems. The `CFBundleExecutable` in `Info.plist` specifies `MeshLab`, but the binary in the Contents/MacOS folder is `meshlab`. The solution is to edit `Info.plist` (change `MeshLab` to `meshlab`) or:

```
cd meshlab.app/Contents/MacOS
ln -s meshlab MeshLab
```

A bug report has been filed here: https://sourceforge.net/p/meshlab/bugs/323/

Comment: Bug still exists on 1.3.3

Answer (score 2):

[Thing (beta, 1.6b24)](http://culturedcode.com/) does not work with HSFX. The solution is to rename or link the `Versions` folder to `versions`

```
cd Things beta.app/Contents/Frameworks/CulturedRuntime.framework
ln -s Versions versions
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with version 2.5.4.

Answer (score 1):

### Console 10.9 (536.100.1) in Maveicks, OS X 10.9.5 (13F1096)

The order of system log queries is dependent upon file system capabilities. This is *troublesome* only if you expect queries to be sorted alphabetically without case sensitivity.

With case-insensitive HFS Plus (a before A): 
[image: Screen shot of a listing with a before A]

With case-sensitive HFS Plus (a after Z):

[image: Screen shot of a listing with a after Z]

Comment: My guess that Console would behave in this way – with HFS Plus with Mavericks – was based on past knowledge of how Console behaved with ZEVO ZFS on Mountain Lion. The relevant topic, in the GreenBytes area (before it was closed by Oracle) was *disorderly representations of files in apps such as Console*; Don Brady described it as a bug in Console.

Answer (score 1):

#### OneDrive

OneDrive won’t synchronize your folder if it’s in a case-sensitive volume. The application itself seems to work, so I created a case-insensitive data volume and moved my OneDrive folder there.

Version: 19.192.0926.0012

Note: I’m using APFS not HFS+ but I think they will cause same issues.

Answer (score 1):

#### Steam

[image: Error message]

I then put the path on a case-insensitive filesystem, but the program exits after update. I then tried manually run the binary from command line (to see whether it provides more detailed error message):

```
/Applications/Steam.app/Contents/MacOS/steam_osx
```

Running this twice and it works. Note that the log is different, so it definitely did something different the second time, even though it looks the same in GUI.

Note: this *doesn’t* mean that all games work. It’s only about Steam itself.

Answer (score 0):

The CrashPlan backup software (v 3.6.3) has a [known case sensitive issue](http://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/Latest/Troubleshooting/CrashPlan_App_3.6.3_Unable_To_Connect_To_Backup_Engine_On_Mac).

Solution is:

1. Open Terminal
2. Stop the CrashPlan service by entering this command:

   `sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.crashplan.engine.plist`
3. Open the CrashPlan plist file by entering this command:

   `sudo nano /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.crashplan.engine.plist`
4. Enter your password for the computer when prompted
5. Locate the following string:

   `<string>/Applications/CrashPlan.app/Contents/MacOs/CrashPlanService</string>`
6. Update it to (note capital s on MacOS):

   `<string>/Applications/CrashPlan.app/Contents/MacOS/CrashPlanService</string>`
7. Press **Control+X** to exit
8. Press **Y** to confirm the changes
9. When you see the prompt **File Name to Write**, press **Enter** to save to the existing location
10. Start the CrashPlan service by typing:

    `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.crashplan.engine.plist`

Comment: I should not expect the same problem with 4.3.0; output from the following command looks fine:

`sudo launchctl list com.crashplan.engine | grep -i macos`

Comment: Correct. Not currently an issue.