# I want to install Adobe CS 6 on an external hard drive but can't select the install location

Tags: filesystem

My SSD is formatted case sensitive, so when I attempted to install I got this:

> Installation on case sensitive volumes isn't allowed. Please choose a case insensitive location.

But I can't select the install location.

Comment: Why is your internal drive formatted case-sensitive? Is there some specific reason this is the case? It's generally considered a bad idea to do that for precisely this reason: you won't be able to install some software.

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46322/what-programs-have-trouble-with-case-sensitive-hfsx-filesystems-and-how-to-fi for list of programs and possible solutions to HSFX (case-sensitive) filesystems.

Comment: @CajunLuke When I bought my SSD I thought that I will have some benefits by formating to case-sensitive. But later I realized that not really. Not even the big guns like Blizard or Adobe pay attention to these benfits... Maybe 3 years later :)

Comment: I also tried to specify the location to be a case insensitive external drive to the downloader but when the installer finally has downloaded then the result was the same... I would consider this a small bug from Adobe (they are checking the filesystem of the main drive not the filesystem of the target location). So I have no other choice than to convert my drive to a less intelligent file system... Those software developers... they always leave some small bugs behind them :)

Comment: @Boti You're not the only one. I formatted one of my Macs HFS+ case-sensitive once in college and had a helluva time getting anything to work. I fail to understand why they even leave the option in Disk Utility, as it's of limited utility and just confuses people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the answer you want, but whatever.

Re-format your SSD to the default of HFS+ case-insensitive. Almost all Mac software is designed to run on a case-insensitive file system and you using case sensitivity is the problem.

Maybe you'll find a solution [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15080/convert-a-partition-from-case-sensitive-to-case-insensitive).

Comment: The application trying to explain to the OS what file system it should use is completely inappropriate on every level, so no, the user choosing a case-sensitive file system is not the problem, even if in this case, the only fix is to give in to the application's unreasonable demands.